# Replacing all tables with a text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to replace all tables in a document with the following text:

"Table 1" (to replace the first table)
"Table 2" (to replace the second table)
...

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and that did not work so we can help.

Comment: @RobertBaron I do not know VBA, but I am intending to learn it. However, I do not have the necessary time to learn it right now and an answer to my question was urgent (deadlines), so I thought maybe someone here would be kind enough to provide a solution -- I guess a solution can be found in just a very few lines of code. Since nobody wanted to help me, I meanwhile did manually the replacement of all tables of my document.

Comment: You did the right thing. SO is not a site where you can get free code! Once you start learning VBA and have problems with specific code, people will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is more elegant and it will probably help you learn these kinds of concepts better.

```
Sub LoopThroughAllTablesinWorkbook()

'PURPOSE: Loop through and apply a change to all Tables in the Excel Workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim sht As Worksheet

'Loop through each sheet and table in the workbook
  For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects

      'Do something to all the tables...
        tbl.ShowTotals = True

    Next tbl
  Next sht

End Sub
```

' Or...

```
Sub tableAllSheet()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    'Loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Loop through all table on a sheet
        For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
            'Print table name, table header row address and data range address to Immediate window
            Debug.Print tbl.Name & vbTab & tbl.HeaderRowRange.Address & vbTab & tbl.DataBodyRange.Address
        Next tbl
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That is very interesting and instructive what you have shared. However, my primary focus was on tables of a MS Word document and not on tables of an Excel document.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing here a solution that I have developed by own:

```
Sub MyMacro()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Delete
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Table" & i
    Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
Next i

End Sub
```